# Wordpress Custom Menu

Tags: wordpress

Am trying to get 3 level top-main menu where in sub menu (child page) of particular parent page should not be visible. I should be like :

- Product

  - Product 1

    - Product 1 A
    - Product 1 B
  - Product 2

    - Product 2 A
    - Product 2 B
  - Product 3

    - NO SUB SUB MENU

I tried `child_of` - but no luck.

Thanks,
oxEgen

Comment: If all else fails (ie you don't get a better solution), could you style out the items based on their ids or class?  eg `#menu-item-52 {display:none}`  Not sure if this'd work with your theme, nor would I "recommend" it as it won't be very robust... but it might be enough for what you're doing.  I've just tested this on a site I'm working on and it worked OK for me.

Comment: CSS would work - but as you said not robust for any further developments - Anyways thanks - let see what else we get.

Answer (score 0):

As per our comment conversation, it would not be robust to rely on arbitrarily generated numbers in id/class attributes on your menu elements.  But if you could *control* how your menu items are attributed, then you can control their style reliably.

I believe the best practice way to handle custom menus is to create a "nav walker", which allows you to control which items are emitted to HTML (and *how* they're emitted).  This would give you the choice of either not rendering the particular menu item(s) you want to avoid, or rendering them with id/class hooks allowing your to style them out.

[This `wp_nav_menu()` tute](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/function-examination-wp_nav_menu/) describes the process of setting up a custom [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), and importantly covers the need to add a custom `Walker_Nav_Menu` class.  This is described in detail in [this Understanding the Walker class tute](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/).

I've hacked up a very basic way to do what you require, based on the page title of the parent item.  This basically "tricks" the `Walker_Nav_Menu` into thinking it has exceeded its allowed traversal depth and hence not following that tree branch, in the instance where your ignored menu node is encountered.  Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
class Selective_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {  

    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) { 

        if (in_array($element->title, array("Product 3"))) // Add any additional items as req'd to this array
            $depth = $max_depth + 1;

        parent::display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output );  
    }  
}
```

And then, wherever your theme adds the nav menu (probably `header.php`), you need to add the `walker` parameter to the `wp_nav_menu()` call (in addition to whatever other parameters you're already using), passing it an instance of your new walker class:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('walker' => new Selective_Walker(), 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'depth' => 3 ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can customize wordpress menu in your own requirement if you have PHP knowledge.I have Build a function that give parent menu and its child menu in an array format and you can customize your wordpress menu up to any level you want.
Here is the [solution](http://subodhdhukuchhu.com.np/get-wordpress-menu-items-in-multidimensional-array/)